# Excel Chart - X-axis values stopping at a certain point

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I really hope someone can help me with this as it's driving me crazy. I have a chart in Excel which is based on a series of dynamic named ranges. When I update the source data, the table extends and the chart with it. I have this system in place for a number of charts which all work fine but this one is giving me grief for some reason.

The problem is that although the range is extending and the chart is linking to the correct data, the x axis labels don't seem to be showing after a certain point. I read somewhere that this may be linked to the axis format. I have date values in there which I have set to show as text as the formatting looked better. The odd thing is if I change to a date axis, the axis is fine but then I lose some of my data from the same point!

[Text axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmxad.png)

[image]

[Date axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JpIU.png)

[image]

I tried changing the chart to use a static data range for the axis, rather than the named range but that didn't help, yet when I create a new chart with a static range it looks fine. If I delete all of the lines from the combo chart and just leave the bars in that also fixes it but I need the lines in there.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this please let me know as I really can't imagine what is wrong with it!

Thanks

Comment: With charts, the devil is in the detail and troubleshooting from screenshots is near impossible. We'd need to be able to inspect the moving parts in the scenario. If you could upload a sample file with non-confidential dummy data to an ad free service like OneDrive or DropBox or Box, we could get a better idea of what is wrong and may be able to suggest a fix or workaround.

Comment: Is it possible that one or more of the series is on a secondary horizontal axis, that you have then hidden (by deleting it)?

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's it! I don't know how it got on there but there does seem to be a different x axis which is based on a static range for the data on the secondary y axis. I have changed this to be the same named range and it now seems to be working. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one or more of the series is on a secondary horizontal axis, that you have then hidden (by deleting it)?
(posting as an answer rather than as a comment)